# Creating a subscription based website in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I'd like to update my website to make it subscription based. It's a ASP.NET Web forms project. I am looking for the following functionality:

1. Ability to have users sign up for
   different plans (Gold, Premium etc)
2. Ability to have users upgrade /
   downgrade to and from plans
3. Ability to hook this up to a Payment
   processor
4. Ability to have a credit based
   system (User buys x credits for $y)
   as an alternative to plans in (1)

Most of this functionality (if not all) is supported by a large number of websites which makes me think I can leverage on an existing framework instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Need more opinions. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating all the necessary logic yourself you could use a subscription payment service like [**chargify**](http://chargify.com/).

This has following advantages:

- you could start immediately with hosted payment pages
- you can accept credit cards for recurring payments without needing them to signup somewhere else (as I've stated PayPal sadly does not provide this option)
- you would not have to deal with all the subscription related programming, like sending out emails, handling charge backs and so on

There are plenty of other subscription payment collection services out there. The once I know are:

- [**recurly**](http://www.recurly.com)
- [**cheddargetter**](http://cheddargetter.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, I'd be definitely interested in a middle man to take care of the business logic. Which of the providers you listed do you prefer and why?

I do understand the advantages at a high level. Would you kind enough to explain in detail? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the Web forms project template, you will need to implement the [Web Profile Builder](http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/02/03/web-profile-builder-for-web-application-projects.aspx) wrapper class to enable access to user profiles. This can be implemented with PayPal. I've done something similar [here](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/07/10/ASPNET-PayPal-Subscriptions-IPN.aspx), hopefully this will point you in the right direction :-)

Comment: Would this implementation be paypal specific. Can I use it with other providers?

Comment: Yes, PayPal services all major credit cards and the user does not have to have a PayPal account to subscribe. You could add SSL or even use a different payment processor if you wish. The potential gotcha here is configuring the profiles correctly to make the subscriptions possible; you need the profiles to store associated data with their membership records :-)

Comment: If you do not have a paypal account you can only make ONE TIME payments which is insufficient in a subscription scenario.
So in fact your users need to have a paypal account or you need to make sure they enter the credit card details every month (or whatever period) again. We are running multiple subscription based websites and made bad experience with the reminders.

Comment: @ntziolis - well spotted! It would stand to reason that they have a PayPal account to set up the recurring payment, thanks :-)

Comment: So, is this where the services like recurly and chargify come in. Their purpose is to help you setup a recurring subscription with Paypal that doesn't support recurring payments?